# React access state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi Trying to learn React right now, still making just baby steps.
I wrote code bellow in codepen(see link on the bottom), in my code I put a few log to console statements I can't figure out why my function `handleSubmit` which is inside upmost component('TodoApp') cannot access state?

I figured it cannot access it because I can print to console text just above 'let current_todos = this.state.todos' but I never see in console text just bellow it.

If this is incorrect how am I supposed to access state then?
NOTE: I realize that a lot of code in that function is redundant but I declare these variables and log statements for debugging purposes

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      todos : [ ] 
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='todo-comp todo-app'>
        <h2>ToDo App</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text">
          </input>
        </form>
        <TodoList todos={this.state.todos}/>
       </div>
    )
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    let new_todo = event.target.children[0].value
    console.log("Submited: ".concat(new_todo))
    let current_todos = this.state.todos
    console.log("Succesfully accessed state")
    this.setState({"todos" : this.state.todos.push(new_todo)})
  }
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <ul className="todo-comp todo-list">
      {this.props.todos.map(
          function(item,key) {
            return(
              <li key={key} className="todo-comp todo-item">{item}</li>
            )
      })}
    </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoApp />,
  document.getElementById('app'),
  console.log("App has been rendered"))
```

[My CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/sgp667/pen/rKxbzB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mistake is that your `handleSubmit` will be recreated on every render.

This code will allow you to see the input value and submit etc. Hope this helps, if you have anymore questions just comment underneath.

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onChange= this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.state = { 
      todos : [ ] 
    }
  }

  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    const { text } = this.state;
    // Your submit value;
    console.log(text)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='todo-comp todo-app'>
        <h2>ToDo App</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange}>
          </input>
        </form>
        <TodoList todos={this.state.todos}/>
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling this.handleSubmit, you should add .bind(this), since the context is different on invocation time. Another option would be to add the following line in the constructor:

```
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
```

Comment: On top of this, if you write a function as an arrow function, it will be treated as having the binding by default:
handleSubmit = (event) => { .... }

Comment: wow I knew it was something simple, you also made me understand why I always see those binds in constructor. So in other words my function was looking for 'this' in wrong environment?

Comment: Using an arrow function in render method is not recommended by TSLint so I personally avoid it. And yes, you were bound to the wrong this, which has no "state" property.